# Roasting multiple turkeys (cooking time estimation)

Tags: roasting, turkey

We tend to aim for large Thanksgiving gatherings, and thus tend to roast the largest turkey we can find.  Last year, we ended up roasting a couple extra turkey legs so we had enough meat.

This year, at the suggestion of a local butcher, I'm considering roasting two smaller birds.  He suggested smaller birds are younger, and would have more tender meat.  Depending on exact sizes, I could possibly get both birds in a large roasting pan, or two smaller roasting pans into one oven.

This leaves me with an odd question, though:  How do I estimate the cooking time for multiple birds?  Do they cook like their combined weight, or more like their individual weights?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like an excellent answer to almost exactly the same question, found [here](http://allrecipes.com/howto/turkey-cooking-time-guide/).

**Tuxman**
Nov. 26, 2013 11:01 am

> I am trying to get a clear answer on cooking 2-15 lbs birds in
>   different pans/same oven. what would the cooking time, same 20 min per
>   lb on 325 degrees? for convection oven?

**dae**
Nov. 27, 2013 12:43 pm

> @Tuxman: Each bird cooks separately. So it is like cooking one 15 lb
>   bird. Start at same time. If one is bigger, it will take longer than
>   the other. Allow max space between them. Put a digital probe deep in
>   the thigh of the smaller one (avoid contact with bone), and take out
>   when it gets to 165 take it out. Put probe in larger one, into thigh,
>   take out when it gets to 165.